# how-to switch resx at runtime?

Tags: c#, internationalization, resx

I have a second resx file Strings.ps-ps.resx that I want to point my code to at runtime. Each resx has Designer.cs with a unique class name.  Do I have to switch/wrap these things myself? ...or is there some built in approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your UI Culture to use a different resx file. This can be done in config

```
<globalization uiCulture="es" culture="es-MX" />
```

or in code

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");;
```

If you want to automatically adapt to the user, you can query the `HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages` for the users browser settings