# How do I change the current Resource Manager at runtime to switch languages?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, localization

I have a C# application and I'm trying to make it support multiple languages by referencing different resx files using the resource manager.

I have this code in my Designer.cs:

```
        [global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    public static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager ResourceManager {
        get {
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(resourceMan, null)) {
                global::System.Resources.ResourceManager temp = new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("project.resources.en-US", typeof(resources.en-US).Assembly);
                resourceMan = temp;
            }
            return resourceMan;
        }
    }
```

How can I switch `System.Resources.ResourceManager("project.resources.en-US", typeof(resources.en-US).Assembly)` to `System.Resources.ResourceManager("project.resources.it-IT", typeof(resources.it-IT).Assembly)` at runtime without modifying my Designer.cs code? Is it possible?

[This question is related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479922/how-to-switch-resx-at-runtime)

*Edit: To clarify, I realize I'm not supposed to change my designer code, but I'm trying to make it so that I access a different resx file. I apologize if my question was ill-worded, but I guess I don't completely understand what I'm talking about. I'm currently looking into satellite assemblies.*

Comment: Don't edit the code in the Designer.cs file, the default code there is culture independent.  You'll lose these changes anyway.  Resource switching is automatic based on the system language.  Lookup "satellite assemblies" in the MSDN library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just change current culture info and the job should be done. `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");`

Comment: It seems to work, although I am unaware of the magic by which it functions. Thank you sir.

Comment: It's very simple. CurrentUiCulture holds the locale for current thread. If you set it to ru-RU, it will load data from russian resource file for current thread, and not whole app. There is also CurrentCulture property which is responsible for globalization tasks, such as decimal separator character, currency and so on. take a look http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx <-- here